# How should I store these Google country IDs for Search Trends in my feed wrapper?

Tags: xml, web-scraping, feed, google-trends

I apologize if the question could have been worded or tagged any better.

I'm looking at [this page](https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends) and making a Node.js module to parse their [feed data](https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed) into JSON. My module will also allow the user to select the country for their data, but the website refers to countries via IDs. I can manually hard code them into the module, but I'll never be sure if they ever change.

Hardcoding seems like the best option, but is there a recommended way of doing this? Or is there a list of Google's standard country IDs somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't hard code them.  At least put them in a resource file that your module references.  Since you're using javascript anyway, make the resource file a JSON object itself.

```
[
 {"United States" : "p1"},
 {"someothercountry" : "p2"},
 ...etc...
]
```

Then to load the resource file:

```
var countryCodeMap = require('./countryCodes.json');
```